# nginx rewrite redirect for a folder

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

all...

I am trying to do something in nginx to redirect all calls for files in

```
/images/
```

to become in:

```
/assets/images/
```

can someone help me with the rewrite rule? giving a 301 moved permanently status?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here's the preferred way to do this with newer versions of Nginx:

```
location ~ ^/images/(.*) {
    return 301 /assets/images/$1;
}
```

See https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/ for more info.

Comment: What is `~` for? And the `^` ? Would it work with `$request_uri` instead of `$1` ?

Comment: @ingo See the [location documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). The `~` (tilde) says this is a case-sensitive regex. Otherwise, URLs for `/Images` and `/imAgEs` would match. If this is the desired behavior then make it case-insensitive with `~*`.

Comment: @ingo The `^` (caret) at the front of the regex anchors it to the beginning of the line. Without it, URLs like `/some/plugin/images/blah.jpg` would also match.

Comment: @ingo In this case, `location /images/ {return 301 /assets$request_uri;}` would work. If the redirect does anything other than prepend to the original directory, however (e.g. `/images` -> `/pics`), the regex and `$1` are still necessary.

Comment: You are a true lifesaver @gsf

Answer (score 7):

Add below configuration into your nginx.conf

```
rewrite ^/(images.*) /assets/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: `return 301` instead of rewriting is preferred ( https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites ), see the answer by @gsf