# NGINX: How do I redirect all of the old posts from a /blog url to a /blogs/ url?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

The situation is this:

I moved my site a while ago, and I changed http://www.getridofthings.com/blog to http://www.getridofthings.com/blogs/ to include more authors with their own blogs. The problem now, is that Google Webmaster Tools is telling me I have a bunch of 404s. We deleted the old blog posts because they were poor quality, but I want to collect all of the incoming links from those various blog posts and direct them simply to the /blogs/ url.

How do I write this rule in NGINX? I've tried many methods, and I keep getting "too many redirects" or "redirect loop" errors.

Comment: Show what did you try

Comment: Right now, I'm using this:

    'location /blog(/.*) {
    return 301 http://www.getridofthings.com/blogs/;
    }'

Comment: possible duplicate of [nginx rewrite redirect for a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305189/nginx-rewrite-redirect-for-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
server {
  listen: 127.0.0.1;
  server_name: example.com;

  rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /blogs/$1 redirect;
}
```

It works by saying that it wants `/blog/` to be at the beginning of the url. If there's anything after the `/`, it will be stored in `$1` which is appended to `/blogs/`. There are no redirect loops because `/blogs/` cannot match those conditions.

Redirects that will happen:

- /blog/ to /blogs/
- /blog/blog-article-1/ to /blogs/blog-article-1/

Comment: That resulted in a URL that looks like this: /blogs/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/